# How to cycle all the rows in a table while decrypt them

Tags: php, mysql, sql, encryption

I have a mysql table like this:

id | nickname | items | date | time
1
2
3

in which each entry is encrypted.

What i can do is to call a query like:

```
  $query1="SELECT nickname FROM user$iduser" WHERE id=1;
  $query2="SELECT items FROM user$iduser WHERE id=1";
  $query3="SELECT data FROM user$iduser WHERE id=1";
  $query4="SELECT time FROM user$iduser WHERE id=1";

  $result=$conn->query($query);                                                     
  $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH);
  $nickname = openssl_decrypt( base64_decode( $row['nickname'] ), $encrypt_method, $key2crypt, 0, $iv );

  $result=$conn->query($query2);
  $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH);
  $items = openssl_decrypt( base64_decode( $row['items'] ), $encrypt_method, $key2crypt, 0, $iv );

  $result=$conn->query($query3);
  $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH);
  $data = openssl_decrypt( base64_decode( $row['data'] ), $encrypt_method, $key2crypt, 0, $iv );

  $result=$conn->query($query4);
  $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH);
  $time = openssl_decrypt( base64_decode( $row['time'] ), $encrypt_method, $key2crypt, 0, $iv );

  echo $nickname,",",$items,",",$data,",",$time;
```

And i will obtain:

```
nickname_entry_decrypted,items_entry_decrypted,data_entry_decrypted,time_entry_decrypted
```

What i want is to cycle that for every id inside the table so that the output will be like:

```
nickname_entry_decrypted1,items_entry_decrypted1,data_entry_decrypted1,time_entry_decrypted1  
nickname_entry_decrypted2,items_entry_decrypted2,data_entry_decrypted2,time_entry_decrypted2  
etc..
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: you should be using a single query like `SELECT nickname, items, data, time FROM user`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want some code like:

```
$sql = "SELECT nickname, items, data, time FROM user{$iduser}";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while (null !== ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())) {
    $nickname = openssl_decrypt(
        base64_decode($row['nickname']),
        $encrypt_method,
        $key2crypt,
        0,
        $iv
    );

    $items = openssl_decrypt(
        base64_decode($row['items']),
        $encrypt_method,
        $key2crypt,
        0,
        $iv
    );

    $data = openssl_decrypt(
        base64_decode($row['data']),
        $encrypt_method,
        $key2crypt,
        0,
        $iv
    );

    $time = openssl_decrypt(
        base64_decode($row['time']),
        $encrypt_method,
        $key2crypt,
        0,
        $iv
    );

    echo "{$nickname},{$items},{$data},{$time}\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i think it is near to the solution but i don't understand what is the statement doing: i am selecting from table user$iduser (i.e. user1..user2..) and it needs to stay fixed. I want to cycle only the table id. Is it doing that?  PS: the first line in my code is wrong: $query1="SELECT nickname FROM user$iduser WHERE id=1";

Comment: You have one table for each user?

Comment: yes, and i don't need to change it in this context. Only cycle over all id of that user table

Comment: I edited my answer. Now it should met your requirements.

Comment: Now it works! Thank you so much. I'd like to understand how is it working, may i ask you for an explanation of the first 3 rows?

Comment: In the first row, the SQL statement is assigned to a variable. The statement will select *all* rows from the table. In the 2nd row, the SQL statement will be executed. The code inside `while` loop will be executed as long as MySQL returns data rows from the executed query. For more information about the `fetch_assoc` method take a look into the [MySQLi documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)